# pandas astype key error on reverting column data type after merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of column names and data types as follows:

```
{'ds': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'sensor_id': dtype('int64'), 'm1': dtype('int64'), 'm2': dtype('float64')}
```

Now, I have a merged pandas dataframe which also contain these columns as a result of right merge and change the data type because of NaN volumes.

So, I try and revert back to the original data type as follows:

```
merged = merged.apply(lambda x: x.astype(original[x.name]) if x.name in data_types else x)
```

Here `original` is the well, original data frame.

However, when I do this, I get the error:

```
KeyError: ('Only the Series name can be used for the key in Series dtype mappings.', 'occurred at index ds')
```

Comment: wouldn't `x.name` be just a string?

Comment: Yes, but is that not what we want?

Comment: did you try `original = {'ds':'<M8[ns]',...}`?

Comment: Actually, I just needed to do: `original[x.name].dtype`. It did not like that I am passing a column from a different dataframe here for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

`Series.astype` takes a `dtype` as input, but what you are passing, `original[x.name]`, is a Series.

```py
> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':range(5)})
> df['A'].astype(df['A']) ← What you are doing
KeyError: 'Only the Series name can be used for the key in Series dtype mappings.'
```

`df['A']` is not a dtype. What you really want is the dtype of that series: `df['A'].dtype`. `x` in your lambda is the equivalent of `df['A']` here, which is a Series and therefore so is `original[x.name]`. What you want is for the x column to get *the dtype of* your target column.

```py
> df['A'].dtype
dtype('int64')

> df['A'].astype('int32')
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: A, dtype: int32 ← new 'int32' dtype

> df['A'].astype(df['A'].dtype) ← Use the dtype of the A column
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Therefore, what you need is:

```py
merged = merged.apply(lambda x: x.astype(original[x.name].dtype) if x.name in data_types else x)
```

Passing a column (Series) from another Dataframe isn't the issue, per your comment. You can't pass a column at all.